# Handling a file that may or may not treat all numbers as text

Tags: vba

My function is meant to take in a given input file for vLookup from column 1, starting in row 4, and the input file is going to be updated over time by various users that may not format the same.  I need to be able to go through the file and format all rows's "account number" to text, as our lookup value is text (some contain a letter, others only digits).

The problem I have now is that some rows are already formatted as text (and Excel gives the warning icon of text stored as numb.  Other rows are truly numeric.  The following code fixes those that are already numeric back into text, but then breaks those rows that are text stored as number. I cannot figure out how to differentiate in code those two representations, b/c they both come back `IsNumeric()` as True, but have opposite results from `CStr()`.

```
Dim lastRow As Integer
Workbooks(convertFile).Activate
Range("A4").Select
lastRow = (Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row)

For i = 4 To lastRow
    If IsNumeric(Cells(i, 1).value) Then
        Dim temp As String
        temp = CStr(Cells(i, 1).Text)
        Cells(i, 1).value = temp
    End If
Next i
```

Answer (score 0):

The following VBA changes the "number format" of A4 through A20 to Text - is that what you want?  IsNumeric() is evaluating if the value is numeric.  It sounds like you just want to change how the value is stored - right?

```
Range("A4:A20").Select
Selection.NumberFormat = "@"
```

In any case, if that isn't your exact problem, I think you are trying to determine the numberformat of the cell.

Comment: For some reason that doesn't work.  I've tried selecting the cells the setting the format, they all appear to be text, but vlookup is not finding certain values.  Let me ask the question a different way.  Does anyone know how Excel could treat two values differently if they are both text representations of a number, one shows the green triangle warning message in upper left hand corner of cell, the other does not (and it is the cells that DO NOT that do not work after this formula.)

Comment: I believe that "green triangle" is just something in the user interface to help warn users that something they may think is a number is actually being treated as text.  I don't believe it is being stored any differently.  Something else you might look at is if the value has a leading apostrophe when you view it in the value bar.  This is another way to format a number as text, but having the apostrophe in the value might mess up the vlookup.